# Galois theory Radical extension

Tags: galois-theory

Prove that any splitting field $K/F$ containing a radical extension $R_{t}/F$ is
itself a radical extension.

Comment: Please cite your source, your reason for interest in the question, what you know about the question, where you get stuck, and so on. 
Also, please write "$K$ over $F$" instead of $K=F$, unless you really mean $K=F$.

Comment: @Gerry: litteraly, word for word, the same question [here](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~yazdani/courses/math4400/HW6.pdf)

Comment: @arbautjc, good sleuthing, bad spelling.

Comment: In french, it's *littéralement*, why in hell is it *literally* in english ! :-)

Comment: The homework arbautjc has uncovered is due in October 18th. It is currently April 11th. I would therefore guess that this is someone trying to revise for exams rather than get their homework done for them! Of course, the OP should tell us what they have tried rather than just copy-and-pasting the question...

Answer (score 2):

Is it just me, or the result appears not to be true as stated. (And if I'm correct, this goes back to the [exercise sheet](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~yazdani/courses/math4400/HW6.pdf) discovered by **arbautjc**.)

I mean, we could take $R_{t} = F$, and $K/F$ a splitting field which is not radical.

Or, marginally less trivially, take $K/F$ to be the compositum of a splitting field $E/F$  (of the polynomial $g$) which is not a radical extension and of another splitting field $R_{t}/F$  (of the polynomial $h$) which is a radical extension. So $K/F$ is the splitting field of $g h$, and it is not a radical extension, because $\operatorname{Gal}(K/F)$ has the non-soluble image $\operatorname{Gal}(E/F)$.

Looking at the previous exercises in the set, I think that

1. the mistake goes back to exercise 3 (b), and
2. what is really meant here is that *the normal closure of a radical extension is itself radical.*